# Use AWK to print lines that have a certain string followed by a number greater than 10000

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 Warn=3000
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=200
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 Warn=40000
column1 column2 column3 column4 Warn=100
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=20000
column1 column2 column3 column4 Warn=15000
```

As it can be seen, the number of fields is changing on each line, but the last field is always "Warn=" followed by a number.
I basically want to print all the lines where the "Warn=" string is followed by a number greater than 10000 and sort them from highest number to lowest.

So the result should look like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 Warn=40000
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=20000
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=15000
```

So far I've been able to somewhat achieve what I want by using grep, awk and sort:

```
grep -E 'Warn=[0-9]{5}' file.txt | awk '{ print $NF, $0 }' | sort -rn -k1 | sed 's/Warn=[0-9]* //'
```

Is there an easier way of doing it just with awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for sorted_in:

```
$ awk -F'=' -v OFS='\t' '$NF>10000{a[NR]=$NF; b[NR]=$0} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for (i in a) print b[i]}' file
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 Warn=40000
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=20000
column1 column2 column3 column4 Warn=15000
```

or with any awk plus sort + cut:

```
$ awk -F'=' -v OFS='\t' '$NF>10000{print $NF, $0}' file | sort -nr | cut -f2-
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 Warn=40000
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=20000
column1 column2 column3 column4 Warn=15000
```

Comment: You might want to add `$(NF-1) ~ /Warn$/ && ` to the condition to meet the "Warn" requirement.

Comment: I like your use of the `a` array to allow multiple lines with duplicate key values.

Comment: @glennjackman the OP said `the number of fields is changing on each line, but **the last field is always "Warn="** followed by a number` so there's no need to match on `/Warn/`, the OP was only grepping to test for the number after Warn being 5 digits to satisfy his 1000+ criteria. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Thank you, Ed!

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** Since OP mentioned that Input_file could have `=` for other fields too, could you please try following then.

```
awk '{split($NF,array,"=")} array[1]=="Warn" && array[2]>10000' Input_file | sort -t'=' -k2rn
```

---

Could you please try following(considering that actual Input_file is same as shown samples).

```
awk -F' |=' '$(NF-1)=="Warn" && $NF>10000'  Input_file
```

OR to sort with value use:

```
awk -F' |=' '$(NF-1)=="Warn" && $NF>10000' Input_file | sort -t'=' -k2rn
```

Output will be as follows.

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 Warn=40000
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=20000
column1 column2 column3 column4 Warn=15000
```

Comment: Nice idea using `=` as the sort separator as long as none of the other columns contain a `=`.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir, I have added a fair warning to answer now.

Comment: Very nice idea! Unfortunately the columns also contain random characters, among which there can also be "=" signs.

Comment: @Andy, could you please try my EDIT code and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Thank you, @RavinderSingh13, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @Andy, EDIT code worked fine for me, is it giving you any output?

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> cat warn.txt
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 Warn=3000
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=200
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 Warn=40000
column1 column2 column3 column4 Warn=100
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=20000
column1 column2 column3 column4 Warn=15000

> perl -ne ' { if(m/(\d+)$/s && $1 >  10000) { $warn{$1}=$_; } }  END { foreach $key(reverse sort keys %warn) { print "$warn{$key}" } } ' warn.txt
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 Warn=40000
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 Warn=20000
column1 column2 column3 column4 Warn=15000

>
```